# Why can I not hit breakpoints in one class only in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I can hit breakpoints in all classes except one in my solution. The class I can't hit breakpoints in is an object that is de/serialized from/to xml. Would that have anything to do with this problem?

other info:

- I'm running in Debug mode
- setting Debugger.Break() in my code doesn't work for the problematic class
- a symbol file for my solution is created on build

Comment: I believe this is (at least in part) due to a bug in VS2015. I have had a similar issue where 1 or more of my projects or files will absolutely not acknowledge breakpoints. If I open the identical solution in VS2013 it debugs properly.

Comment: Can you show example code and where you put the breakpoint?

Comment: Doesn´it solve if you clean and rebuild the solution?.

Comment: no, I've already tried that

Comment: What is in this object which a breakpoint needs to hit?

Comment: It now appears to be working, but I don't know what I did....

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, a different class in the same project does get hit.